# Как очистить историю чата в Telegram? (TelegramBots)

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Я использую библиотеку https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots. Версия: `4.1.2`

Требуется написать метод `public void deleteMessages(long chatId, int N)`, где
`chatId` - это ID чата бота с пользователем, `N` - это количество сообщений для удаления (допустим 10 последних сообщений включая сообщения от пользователя).

Для чего мне это нужно:
Чтобы ночью чат с ботом "чистился" и на утро бот готов был слушать новые команды (Пользователи живут в одном городе, поэтому тут приложение локального применения).

Comment: задавали вопрос авторам библиотеки? непонятно, вопрос у вас о Telegram API или о Telegram Bot API?

Comment: @Anatol я ошибся ссылкой на библиотеку... Всегда путаю их. Про вопрос авторам: нет не задавал. Задал здесь ибо кто-то уже мог с такой проблемой сталкиваться

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос, внесите ясность

Comment: @Anatol отредактировал